# Is $f(x) =x^2$ an automorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have found this question [Let $G$ be an Abelian group with odd order. Show that $\varphi : G \to G$ such that $\varphi(x)=x^2$ is an automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738500/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-with-odd-order-show-that-varphi-g-to-g-such-t).

My question is that what would happen if  $G$ has even order? Is $f(x) =x^2$ an automorphism ?

Comment: It won't be an automorphism: given $x$ with order $2n > 0$, then $x^n \neq 1$ but $f(x) = (x^n)^2 = x^{2n} = 1$ shows that $f$ is not injective. (And such an $x$ exists since $G$ cannot be trivial; otherwise it would have order 1.)

Comment: thanks u@Hayden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy's theorem, such a $G$ has an element $x$ of order $2$, so that $x^2=1$. The endomorphism $\varphi$ thus has nontrivial kernel, hence cannot be an automorphism.

Comment: For order $2$, we don't need to use Cauchy's theorem: just pair $g$ and $g^{-1}$. Then there will be an even number of elements such that $g=g^{-1}$, and $e$ is one of them.